# (Wordpress) I changed the template for WooCommerce product for category image but the image is still not displayed

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display category image instead of text on my product archive but looks like something does not work.

For the theme, I am using Phlox Pro with Elementor Builder.

I am using [Category and Taxonomy Image plugin](https://sl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/) and I followed all the steps and then included the code in my woocommerce template, here is how it looks:

```
<?php

        if ( 'default' == $show_cats = auxin_get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_product_related_posts_display_categories', 'default' ) ) {
            $show_cats = auxin_get_option('product_related_posts_display_categories', '1' );
        }

        $show_cats = is_shop() ? auxin_get_option('product_index_display_category', '1' ) : $show_cats;

        if (function_exists('get_wp_term_image'))
        {
            $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term->term_id); 
            //It will give category/term image url 
        }

        if ( auxin_is_true( $show_cats ) && $cat_count > 0 ) {
            echo $meta_image . wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<em class="auxshp-meta-terms">', '</em>' );
        } ?>
```

I expect the output to be a category image like this (on the left):

[image]

But instead, I get no change (on the right):

[image]